# Screen turns black after booting, backlight only works in recovery mode on an Acer Aspire 5736z

Tags: acpi

the screen turns black after booting. you need to use spotlight to see what is what is displayed on the screen but the backlight works on recovery mode. so my question is how can this problem be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Backlight sometimes gives problem due to grub misconfiguration. You need to edit the grub and edit it. Here is what you have to do.

- As root edit `/etc/default/grub`
- Change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`
  save the file
  and then `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

That will solve your problem.