# How to edit the GRUB file

Tags: grub2

The backlight of my Acer Aspire 5336 screen turns off when Ubuntu 12.04 is installed.
I found that it could be corrected by editing the GRUB file
[Screen turns black after booting, backlight only works in recovery mode on an Acer Aspire 5736z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133894/screen-turns-black-after-booting-backlight-only-works-in-recovery-mode-on-an-ac/133906#133906?newreg=3c2e9bfa240a4f6abf5d3de5b7b368b3)

But since I cannot do so via Ubuntu (as the backlight is turned off) how can I edit the GRUB file?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to edit system configuration files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files)

Comment: I think not. I cannot do anything from Ubuntu OS because the screen is black! I'm looking for a way to do so from Windows

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+F1 bring you to a terminal? Try to login in there with your credentials and use `nano` to edit files. You can also edit GRUB menuentries from within GRUB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could boot to a live CD and edit GRUB that way, or you can do it whilst in GRUB itself, much faster:

- Highlight "Ubuntu" in the GRUB menu, but rather than hitting <kbd>Return</kbd> to boot Ubuntu, hit the letter <kbd>e</kbd>. This will take you to an editor.

If you never see a list of operating systems to boot, holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> as the computer loads will display it.

- Add `acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor` at the end of the second-to-last line, as shown in the picture:

[image: See the second-to-last line.]

- Hit <kbd>F10</kbd>, which will boot Ubuntu, backlight and all.
- You can then make the change permanent by following the instructions in the answer you referred to.

Comment: thank you.. but can u tell me whats meant by "quiet splash" in second bullet point

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: So I've updated my answer to make it hopefully a little more clear. "Quiet splash" are two boot options, one shows the Ubuntu splash screen ("Ubuntu" with the loading dots, I think) and one prevents the terminal gubbins from being shown as Ubuntu loads. It makes the boot process look a little smoother, rather than having reams of commands flying up the screen which most people don't care about.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try to edit the file using a external monitor?

Because if you can't edit the file and update Grub with the actual installation, you have to bind the installed OS using a LiveCD or LiveUSB (http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) and then edit the /etc/default/grub and update Grub.

Comment: It sort of worked! You still have to adjust the brightness using the keyboard and in my case it is decreasing the brightness that worked!!